# fail2ban custom script start function

Tags: python, python-2.7, fail2ban

I have made my own custom action for fail2ban. It is a script write in Python.
I have created the following function according to the documentation:

- ***_init*_**
- **start** : When fail2ban start
- **stop** : When fail2ban stop
- **ban** : When fail2ban ban an ip
- **unban** : When fail2ban unban an ip

I use this action for many jails and it seems that for each jails fail2ban call the start function and in my case create a new rule iptables.
So I have many duplicate iptables rules because fail2ban call several time  the start function.

I have tried to put a condition. "If the rule doesn't exist I create it". But all jails seems to be started in thread. With this condition I can limited the duplicate rules to 2 or 3.

Is there a tricks or a permanent solution ? Maybe semaphore during the start function or lock a file or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolve my issue by using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

/usr/bin/fail2ban-server 

grep "^\[" /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/* | grep -v "#" | cut -d"[" -f 2 | cut -d "]" -f 1 | while read jail
do
    load=$(uptime | cut -d ":" -f5 | cut -d"," -f 1)
    compare=$(bc <<< "$load>3")
    while [[ $compare -eq "1" ]]
    do
        echo -e "Load too ${RED}high${NC} ($load) .... sleep 5 secondes"
        sleep 5
        load=$(uptime | cut -d ":" -f5 | cut -d"," -f 1)
        compare=$(bc <<< "$load>3")
    done    

    echo -n -e "$1 starting jail $jail ..."
    fail2ban-client reload $jail
    echo -e "[${GREEN}OK${NC}] "

done
```

It will get every jail in jail.d et start them by using the command fail2ban-client reload  (doesn't work with fail2ban-client start ) and with taking care of the load of the server.

The jails will not start one after another and my initial condition will works